# Error on Instantiation Form

Tags: infopath

Hi all I have an eror when opening the Instantiation_Form

There has been an error while loading the form.

The specified form cannot be found.

Whith SPD I can see that form and open it.

In my code I have

......

InstantiationUrl="_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx"

....

urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:FormInitiere:-myXSD-2011-10-07T08-43-42

I've tried With full trust and Domain trust (same error)

I've checked my ItemMetadata connection and it's there.

What should I check ?

In logs I can't find any errors.

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved
For some unknown reason the feature Receiver Assembly has changed to my assembly (VS Token) not to Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
Same with Receiver Class.
Now it's working
Thank's